# Merge [facebook-iphone-sdk] into [facebook-ios-sdk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

These two tags seem to be duplicates for the Facebook SDK for iOS.  So, I think [facebook-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-iphone-sdk) (161) should be merged into [facebook-ios-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ios-sdk) (961).

Comment: there is a suggested synonym.

Comment: Oh good, that means it'll get approved in about two years.

Comment: @Charles: you are too optimist...

Comment: @DanielA.White After some digging, I found where to look that up.  Still, hopefully this will raise awareness to get it cleaned up.  :)

Comment: A great point @Charles.   (Meanwhile some idiot will add fb-iPad-sdk !)

Comment: If the synonym hasn't been approved within a reasonable amount of time we could just manually retag them? It's only ~150 posts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have migrated all [facebook-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-iphone-sdk) questions to [facebook-ios-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ios-sdk).  Thanks for the review everyone.

Answer (score 13):

Yes of course, obviously, do this.  Nice spot.